# Linq from TABLE select *

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to select of all fields from a table I try to do this using to following code and I get the **error** notification *class name is not valid at this point*

```
from item in context.CreateQuery<permitdocumentfields>()
where item.Id == new Guid(Request["view"])
select new 
       { permitdocumentfields }
```

How to make this stuff to work like `FROM TABLE SELECT *`?

Comment: you can check this post of mine to learn linq from sql : http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html

Comment: If you wanted to wrap each result row in a new anonymous type and alias the return property, you could do 'select new {permitdocumentfields = item}', but in your case, I suspect just doing 'select item' is sufficient as @Pranay recommended.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
from item in context.CreateQuery<permitdocumentfields>()
where item.Id == new Guid(Request["view"])
select item
```

Check the post for more detail : [SQL to LINQ ( Visual Representation )](http://pranayamr.blogspot.com/2010/12/sql-to-linq-visual-representation.html)

**Simple select** 
[image]

**Select with the filter and select new** 
[image]

**Note** : `select new` is require when you want to construct new object only.